# in R programming, concerning on inverse matrix and its multiplication

Tags: r, matrix-inverse

this is my solving process from the exercise of [a beginner's guide to R]

```
> Q
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    2    1
[3,]    2    3    0
> solve(Q)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] -0.12  0.36 -0.16
[2,]  0.08 -0.24  0.44
[3,]  0.32  0.04 -0.24
> solve(Q)%*%Q
     [,1]          [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1 -2.775558e-17    0
[2,]    0  1.000000e+00    0
[3,]    0  0.000000e+00    1
```

I wonder why I cannot get to the right answer that the identity matrix should come out.

Comment: In what sense do you think that -2.77e-17 is meaningfully different from 0?

Comment: can you explain it more?

Comment: As mentioned below, no computer (any language) can do _exact_ computations in all circumstances due to floating point issues. The sort of canonical reference on this is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (among many other places, if you Google it).

Comment: thanks. it might be helpful. but to understand "floating point arithmetic" I think I should study further. anyhow, all right. thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Use the `zapsmall` function on the final result.  Due to floating point representation and rounding errors anything more than simple arithmatic (and even that sometimes) will result in values that are very close, but not exactly the same as what is expected.  In this case you are seeing a value that has 16 0's after the decimal place before the first non-zero digit.  The `zapsmall` function will convert these small, essentially 0, values to 0 so that what you see matches what you expect.

Comment: +1 - ya learn something new every day. Thanks for this function.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a programming error, this is the result of what's called "floating point arithmetic." rounded to a reasonable length, you will get the identity matrix:

```
Q2 <- solve(Q)%*%Q
round(Q2, 4)
```

To learn more on floating point arithmetic [**go here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Floating-point_arithmetic_operations).